# House shakes subtly every so often

Tags: foundation, structural

my house shakes subtly every so often, and it doesnt seem like there is any rhyme or reason to it. We dont live close to public transportation, theres never an earthquake reported in the area, and as far as i know, we dont live by any kind of plants that would be doing very heavy moving.

Comment: Washing machine on spin cycle? I can feel our machine on the other side of the house if there's a big load and it's not perfectly balanced.

Comment: does it happen more in late fall and early spring? that's thermal expansion causing settling; perfectly normal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you talked to your neighbors?  If it's a local/regional business of some sort people who've lived there longer than you likely know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google Maps (or Bing or whatever) and turn on the "satellite view" layer to look for a stone quarry within a few miles of your house.

My house shakes about once a week from blasting at a quarry that's about a mile away. First you feel a rumble in your feet, which is the vibration that comes through the ground, then within about 4-5 seconds you can hear the sound of the blast through the atmosphere. This quarry produces mostly crushed stone.

If you live in an area that's not a desert, you can identify a quarry as a beige colored patch of ground in satellite view, which contrasts nicely with forested areas.

Also, I know someone in Texas who lives about a mile from a railroad switch yard, and he feels vibrations from that from time to time as heavy rail cars bang into each other.